# error while creating mount source path mkdir /host_mnt/d: file exists

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

i run docker-compose up -d
report error

```
D:\project\c\test\docker>docker-compose up -d
Starting debug ... error

ERROR: for debug  Cannot start service gdbserver: error while creating mount source path '/host_mnt/d/project/c/test/docker': mkdir /host_mnt/d: file exists

ERROR: for gdbserver  Cannot start service gdbserver: error while creating mount source path '/host_mnt/d/project/c/test/docker': mkdir /host_mnt/d: file exists
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:cosmic

########################################################
# Essential packages for remote debugging and login in
########################################################

RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y && apt-get install -y \
    apt-utils gcc g++ openssh-server cmake build-essential gdb gdbserver rsync vim

RUN mkdir /var/run/sshd
RUN echo 'root:root' | chpasswd
RUN sed -i 's/PermitRootLogin prohibit-password/PermitRootLogin yes/' /etc/ssh/sshd_config

# SSH login fix. Otherwise user is kicked off after login
RUN sed 's@session\s*required\s*pam_loginuid.so@session optional pam_loginuid.so@g' -i /etc/pam.d/sshd

ENV NOTVISIBLE "in users profile"
RUN echo "export VISIBLE=now" >> /etc/profile

# 22 for ssh server. 7777 for gdb server.
EXPOSE 22 7777

RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash debugger
RUN echo 'debugger:pwd' | chpasswd

########################################################
# Add custom packages and development environment here
########################################################

########################################################

CMD ["/usr/sbin/sshd", "-D"]
```

docker-compose.yaml

```
# From: https://github.com/shuhaoliu/docker-clion-dev/blob/master/docker-compose.yml

version: '3'

services:
  gdbserver:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    image: clion_dev
    security_opt:
      - seccomp:unconfined
    container_name: debug
    ports:
      - "7776:22"
      - "7777:7777"
    volumes:
      - .:/home/debugger/code
    working_dir: /home/debugger/code
    hostname: debug
```

Answer (score 15):

I also experienced this issue (using Docker Desktop for Windows). For me, I simply issued a restart for Docker by using the following steps:

1. Locate the Docker Desktop Icon (in the Windows Task Bar)
2. Right-Click the Docker Desktop Icon and choose "Restart..."
3. Click the "Restart" button on the confirmation dialog that appears

When Docker Desktop had restarted, I then:

1. Checked for running containers using docker-compose ps
2. Stopped any running containers using docker-compose down
3. Started the containers docker-compose up

And Voila! All containers restarted successfully with no mount errors.

Comment: This worked! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Right click on Docker on Window icon > **Setting** > **Share driver** > **Reset credentials ...** . For me that fix the problems.

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YNhjD.png)