# Error: /run/desktop/mnt/host/c/Users/Asus/namatus/db/data': mkdir /run/desktop/mnt/host/c: file exists

Tags: node.js, docker, dockerfile, nestjs

well, after I run docker-compose up or --build,I've never experienced this error, I have no idea how to resolve it.,  I'm getting this error:

```
Error response from daemon: error while creating mount source path '/run/desktop/mnt/host/c/Users/Asus/namatus/db/data': mkdir /run/desktop/mnt/host/c: file exists
```

Docker-compose:

```
version: '3'
services:
  rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq:3-management
    container_name: rabbitmq
    hostname: rabbitmq
    volumes:
      - /var/lib/rabbitmq
    ports:
      - '5672:5672'
      - '15672:15672'
    env_file:
      - .env

  auth:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: ./apps/auth/Dockerfile
    env_file:
      - .env
    depends_on:
      - rabbitmq
      - postgres
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app 
      - /usr/src/app/node_modules
    command: npm run start:dev auth 
  namatus:
    build: 
      context: ./
      dockerfile: ./apps/namatus/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - '4000:5000'
    env_file:
      - .env
    depends_on:
      - rabbitmq
      - auth
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app 
      - /usr/src/app/node_modules
    command: npm run start:dev namatus

  postgres:
    image: postgres
    env_file:
      - .env
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'
    volumes:
      - ./db/data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

  postgres_admin:
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    env_file:
      - .env
    ports:
      - '15432:80'
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json .

RUN npm install

COPY . .
```

Does anyone know what is causing this? and I also have another one that hasn't helped me yet, but to resolve this one, I need to resolve this one first that I wasn't receiving.

Comment: these answers helped me, specifically the 1 answer, the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59526444/error-while-creating-mount-source-path-mkdir-host-mnt-d-file-exists